# How to know for what purpose Common Apache libraries is used in java class file

Tags: java, maven, shared-libraries

I am quiet new to java and there are `Common Apache libraries` being used in `java` project :

```
Maven: org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7
Maven: org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.3
Maven: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.6.1
Maven: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.6.1
Maven: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.6.1
Maven: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.6.1
```

This common libraries have been used by the other projects as well. So how can i check for what purpose this libraries are being used for and in which java class files ?

Comment: Well, you could try removing them one by one from your build specs and compile the code again, the code that is calling them should throw compile error and you will be able to see the lines in log that are using any function from this. That would be quick step, without using an IDE specific feature. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: i am using eclipse and Intellij both ...actually this is bit risk to delete the files and reimport again as i have to generte target files everytime

Comment: there is dependency:analize https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html that helps to find out if a dependency is used at all. Other than that I only know looking into the jars, hoping it only uses one main package and then searching for imports for that package